# How should I use searchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, controller

How should I use search controller instead of searchDisplayController in   tableView method

I have an example code here

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

Hhere I am getting error on this line it says searchDisplayController is deprecated.

```
 @implementation LocationsViewController 

 {

NSArray *_park;

 }

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self->_park     count]];


   // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
   JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
   NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"park" withExtension:@"json"];

// Load the data on a background queue...
// As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    _park = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];
    // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

}

```
  //Just before showing the LocationDetailViewController, set the selected Location object
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
LocationDetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
vc.location = [_park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

}

```
 #pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods
 //UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];




  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

Location *location = [_park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = location.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.address;
```

// cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.ide;
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location_image"];

```
 ///////////////////

   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self->_park[indexPath.row];
}

 /////////////////

return cell;
```

}

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 //////////////////////////////////////////////


if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    return [self.searchResult count];
}
else
{
    return [self->_park count];
}


 //////////////////////////////////////////////

return [_park count];
```

}

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////



  - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:   (NSString*)scope
```

{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

```
self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self->_park filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

}

```
    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

{

```
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope: [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar  selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];


return YES;
```

}

@end

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: do you have answer for this then help

Comment: I don't know how to answer that if I have no idea what language of frameworks it is.

Comment: If you are trying to handle cellForRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath differrently for your tableView and UISearchResultsController and hence the condition you mentioned above then UISearchController has a property named searchResultsController :) So you can compare  if (tableView == self.yourSearchController. searchResultsController) provide little more code to understand the context, simply writing one line of code wont help much

Comment: here is my code @ sandeep

Comment: @Vicky : you can use my comment then :) You must be having a reference to UISearchController instance lets say mySearchController :) in cellForRowAtIndexPath simply check if (tableView == self. mySearchController. searchResultsController ) Thats all buddy :)

Comment: no its not working sandeep

Comment: ok can you post your code for UISearchController declaration ???

Comment: @vicky : Wait for my answer :)

Comment: @vicky : I have added my answe with explaination :) have a look :)

Comment: @vicky : Did my answer worked for you ? or still struggling ???

Comment: see my whole code right from implementation

Comment: @vicky : SearchDisplayController is deprecated now :) Try moving your code to UISearchController :) UISearchController is almost similar to UISearchViewController and SearchDisplayController in its delegate pattern :)

Comment: @vicky : I cant write whole code for how to use UISearchController so providing you the link https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial follow it :) should not be much change in the code :)

Comment: thats what i am trying to do but not making up to it ...

Comment: @vicky : Follow raywenderlich tutorial :) Its very clearly explained :)

Comment: and one more thing i am loading name and address in cell from main bundle ...but don't know how to get image from that park array so plz help

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

Location *location = [_park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = location.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.address;

Comment: how to get image in cell here

Comment: you can make use of SDWebImage to download the image for you :) That will also improve the smoothness of you app as it caches the images it downloads :) Provide the url to it once downloaded set the image to you'r cell's ImageView :) Thats all :) Read this for understanding how to use it https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: no dude u did not get my point i have all image data in json file in my application and i am fetching that data like i did in cell for row at index .. Location *location = [_park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = location.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.address;     and like these i want to display image in my cell... _park is my json data file i can fetch text successfully using label but i want to fetch image now

Comment: What do you mean by image data ?? You mean path to image in NSBundle or binary image data???

Comment: path to image in NSBundle

Comment: @vikcy : If your images are in bundle then, [cell.ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageInBundle.png"]];

Comment: do i need to use custom property for the cell and add image view then use....or i can simply use  image in that table view cell property in that attribute pane

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have declared a `UISearchController` by passing `nil` as a parameter to `searchResultsController`. So your same `tableView` is being used as `searchResultsController` of `UISearchController`

like

`let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`
or

```
UISearchController searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
```

I hope all you want to do now is to distinguish whether `UISeacrhController` is active or it's your `tableView` so that you can show different cell for them :)

If so,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

    Location *location = [_park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = location.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.address;
 // cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.ide;
//  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location_image"];

       if (searchController.active)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = self->_park[indexPath.row];
    }

     /////////////////

    return cell;
}
```

My answer in comment `if (tableView == self.yourSearchController. searchResultsController)` would have worked if you had instantiated a different tableView controller and provided as `SearchResultsController` for `UISearchController`

But because you have specified `nil` in your `init` of `UISearchController`same tableView instance will be used as `SearchResultsController`. So comparing will result in always yes :)

Rather, you can depend on `active` property of `UISearchController` and check in what context tableView is being used and handle it appropriately :)

Hope I made my point clear :) Happy coding :)

Comment: @vicky : You chose a wrong tutorial :) thats the only mistake :) Dude he is using SearchDisplayController which is deprecated in iOS8. Title of tutorial clearly says it is for iOS 7. Anyway did my answer helped you ??? In case you wanna learn how to use UISearchController in swift refer this https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Comment: Thank sandeep for helping....but i did not declare any search controller by passing nil...so this answer won't help me...what should i do? and its giving me error

Comment: @vicky : Dude post your whole code :) and if you are using searchDisplayController try moving your code to UISearchController following the tutorial I have provided :)